# New Connection String with Office 365

Tags: office365, oledb, hta

I have an HTA application that has worked for years with no issue, and I am now having issues since being forced to update to Office 365.

Here is the connection string:

```
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=<file name>.xls;" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"";"
```

Here is the error I now get:
Error: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.
Code: 0

I have scoured this site and others looking for and trying solutions.

I have tried with the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" and "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable" installed, not installed.

I have tried any and all combinations of Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.8.0, Excel 12.0, Excel 16.0.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If that's the web-based version of Excel, that would explain it. Otherwise, maybe this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/updates/control-block-ole-com) is relevant.

Comment: Thank you for replying! It is not a full web-based solution. I do still have .exe Office products on my computer with this installation.

I will try some items in that link and see if it gets anywhere.

Comment: Also, apparently "click to run" Excel does not work. It has to be the full install via the MSI. Reference found [here](https://community.appeon.com/index.php/qna/q-a/ole-automation-with-office-click-to-run-install).

Comment: Even easier than trying to figure out how to recode this was making the default application for *.hta files C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe. Haven't found any unintended consequences yet. Make sure to have Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable and/or Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable installed. Had both installed... not sure which is required.

Comment: HTA files normally are associated with the 32 bit version of MSHTA on 64 bit machines. That is, the standard association is normally `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe`. Maybe something or someone had recently changed it to the 64 bit version (`C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe`) on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even easier than trying to figure out how to recode this was making the default application for *.hta files C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe. Haven't found any unintended consequences yet. Make sure to have Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable and/or Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable installed. Had both installed... not sure which is required.

Comment: HTA files normally are associated with the 32 bit version of MSHTA on 64 bit machines. That is, the standard association is normally `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe`. Maybe something or someone had changed it to the 64 bit version: `C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe`